# Groovy++ and XML

Tags: xml, groovy, groovy++

Can be used statically typed Groovy++ for XML processing?

Example (for testing you can use [Groovy++ web console](http://gppconsole.appspot.com/)):

```
@Typed package test
def CAR_RECORDS = '''
  <records>
    <car name='HSV Maloo' make='Holden' year='2006'>
      <country>Australia</country>
      <record type='speed'>Production Pickup Truck with speed of 271kph</record>
    </car>
  </records>
'''

def records = new XmlSlurper().parseText(CAR_RECORDS)
println records.car
​
```

The result:

```
startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 14: Cannot find property car of class GPathResult
 @ line 14, column 9.
   records.car
           ^

1 error
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like it...  You can use:

```
@Typed(TypePolicy.MIXED)
```

and then

```
println records.car
```

works, but you cannot get to attribute values via:

```
println records.car.@name
```

As you then get the error:

```
Cannot find field name of class Object
```

I guess XmlSlurping is currently a bit too dynamic for groovy++

Comment: I couldn't get `@Typed(TypePolicy.MIXED)` to work (unresolved symbol), but removing `@Typed package test` all together solved the problem

Comment: @ronk - Removing `@Typed package test` you compile it with groovy and not groovy++